# syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, php-7.4, php-8

**Context**
I just finished developing an internal business application using Laravel/Jetstream with Inertia which uses a Model Broadcaster with Ably integrated for desktop notifications. Everything was working perfectly locally so I pushed live this afternoon. I have everything migrated and what appears to be setup properly, with https working.

The server is a LEMP droplet on DO
Link to the image details: https://marketplace.digitalocean.com/apps/lemp?ipAddress=143.198.148.3#getting-started

**Issue:**
Everything I have read about the issue says it's likely a php version issue being earlier than 7.4, but this isn't the case here

**The result of phpinfo():**(I can't include the image because I just signed up today)

```
PHP Version 7.4.3
```

Image located at:
https://i.ibb.co/C1qZyjZ/Screen-Shot-2021-07-21-at-3-56-20-PM.png

**The result of var_dump(PHP_VERSION)**

```
string(5) "7.4.3"
```

Inside of my Model Broadcaster is the origination of the error.

`namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\BroadcastsEvents;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;

class Ticket extends Model
{
    use BroadcastsEvents, HasFactory;

    /**
     * Get the channels that model events should broadcast on.
     *
     * @param  string  $event
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn($event)
    {
        return match($event) {
            //
            //This is the line
            //
            'created' => [new Channel('ticket')],
            default => []
        };
    }
}`

Laravel Documentation showing the same format:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting#model-broadcasting

`/**
 * Get the channels that model events should broadcast on.
 *
 * @param  string  $event
 * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
 */
public function broadcastOn($event)
{
    return match($event) {
        'deleted' => [],
        default => [$this, $this->user],
    };
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match is php8 feature. You can update php7.4 to 8 or use switch

```
switch($event)
    case 'created':
        return [new Channel('ticket')];
    default:
        return [];
endswitch;
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I had completely forgotten that I upgraded locally.